# asio::async_write SEG FAULT

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, callback, boost-asio

I am not sure why I am getting a segmentation fault when I begin an async_write() with a string as a buffer. I have successfully used this function in the past.

Here is the method where I get the segmentation fault:

```
void StringSocket::sendLine(const string& toWrite)
{
    try
    {
    std::cout << "in StringSocket::sendLine()\n";
    std::cout << "is the socket alive?: " << (bool)s->is_open() << "\n";
    std::cout << "toWrite: " << toWrite;

     //s = asio::ip::tcp::socket* 
     asio::async_write(*this->s,
           asio::buffer(toWrite),
           boost::bind(&StringSocket::MessageSent,
                   this,
                   asio::placeholders::error));
  std::cout << "AFTER: asio::async_write()\n";

    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << e << "\n";
    }
}
```

here is what the compiler says:

```
in main()
in serverTCP::serverTCP()!
in spreadsheet::spreadsheet()
in serverTCP::start_accept()!
in client::client(asio::io_service& io_service, std::string name)
in StringSocket::StringSocket(asio::ip::tcp::socket *_socket)
in client::getSocket()
in StringSocket::underSoc()
in serverTCP::pickSpreadsheet()!
in client::getClientName()
in client::sendToGui(std::string mess)
in StringSocket::beginSend(const string& toWrite, sendCallback callBack, void* payload)
toWrite: Welcome to SS! user: user0000
in StringSocket::ProcessSend()
TextToSend: Welcome to SS! user: user0000
in StringSocket::sendLine()
is the socket alive?: 1
toWrite: Welcome to SS! user: user0000
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the reference for [`async_write`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write.html) (all the overloads says the same on this subject) it will tell you that the handler function takes two arguments, first the error code and then the length of the sent data.

Your `boost::bind` call only provides *one* argument. You still have to tell `boost::bind` that there is an extra argument that will be filled in later. You do that with the placeholder argument, `boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred`:

So change it to e.g.

```
boost::bind(&StringSocket::MessageSent,
            this,
            asio::placeholders::error,
            asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
```

Comment: instead of _2, one should use `boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred` ; Also, if that were the case, it would fail on compilation, not during runtime.

Comment: Actually, it might fail on runtime, but it should at least have printed the `AFTER: asio::async_write()` message

Comment: It's a CT issue. How does it answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
asio::async_write(*this->s, asio::buffer(toWrite),...
```

Note that `asio::buffer` is just an adapter that doesn't copy its argument. So, in the above line you actually pass a *local* object as a buffer to the async. operation. Thus, there's a race condition between the `toWrite` lifespan and the async. operation.